# jquery attr(name,value) method's value parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading Bibeault's jQuery in Action and I'm having troublel understanding the `value` parameter of the `attr()` method. The book says that the parameter can be a function whose parameters are `index` and `previousValue`. What is the purpose of these parameters? I don't understand the text's explanation.

Specifically I want to know:

1. Are these parameters mandatory?
2. What is an example of how these parameters are used?
3. Can I use other parameters within the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No parameters are mandatory in javascript. You use whatever amount you want. These parameters are available for you in your function.

2) examples:

Let's say you have this html:

```
<a href="#" title="Google"></a>
<a href="#" title="Yahoo"></a>
<a href="#" title="Bing"></a>
```

Now, run this snippet:

```
$('a').attr('title', function(index, previousValue){
    return previousValue + ' - An external link';
});
```

This will add the string " - An external link" to the end of every title.

Now, look at this:

```
$('a').attr('title', function(index, previousValue){
    return previousValue + ' - Link number ' + index;
});
```

This will result in the following html:

```
<a href="#" title="Google - Link number 0"></a>
<a href="#" title="Yahoo - Link number 1"></a>
<a href="#" title="Bing - Link number 2"></a>
```

As you can see, you can see, these parameters are very handy.

3) Not sure what you mean by using other parameters. Please clarify.

---

It seems that you are not familiar with Javascript's scope lookup chain. You do not have to explicitly pass parameters to a function. If they're defined in a scope above it, the function will have access to it:

```
var num1 = 23;
var num2 = 54;

$('a').attr('title', function(){
    return num1 + num2;
});
```

Comment: @Joseph_Silber--suppose I wanted to set the attribute to the sum of two numbers calculated by a function:

`$('div').attr('sum',function(a,b) {return a + b});`

Comment: `$('a').attr('title', function(){ return 12 + 45 });`

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty simple. The `attr()` function has three possible modes; the one you refer to takes a callback to get the value.

For example:

```
 $('.someClass').attr('rel', function(index, value)
 {
      // index refers to the elements index of the set; so of all elements with the
      //    css class 'someClass', the index will refer to that position in the list.
      //    If three elements match, the callback will be invoked 3 times, with 0, 1, 2
      //    as the index when each element, respectively, is invoked. 

      // value refers to the current value of the attribute. 

      // Return the value you want to set.
      return 'SomeRelValue';
 });
```

The parameters are not mandatory; if you simply omit them from the callback signature, you simply dont have access to that information. You cannot pass other parameters to this method. You might want to use this function when you will match a lot of elements, and want to insert some data based on their ordinal position of the selector element.

For example:

```
 $('.someElements').attr('rel', function(index, value)
 {
      return value + index;
 });
```

For each element matching the selector, you set the rel attribute to what it was plus the index of the selector. So element one, if it had a rel of 'sampleRel', is set to 'sampleRel1', element two with rel' sampleRel' becomes 'sampleRel2', etc etc

Comment: @Tejs--so i cannot use a function to set a value that is *not* based on another element's position? That seems kind of nearsighted...

Comment: The index parameter is only extra information. It has no bearing on your ability to set attributes.

Answer (score 0):

attr is a way to access attributes on an element. the overload which allows a function will allow you to use the function return to set the value (the index param to the function would be the index into the selection, previousValue being the value it had until now).

I've never used this overload myself, but assume it would be nice if you're making attribute values based on some sort of function.

They are not mandatory, passing different number of parameters gives different functionality:

attr('name') - gets the value of name

attr('name','value') - sets the value of name

attr('name',function(i,v){return v+i;}); - sets the value of name to the previous value + the index in the collection.

example:
lets say we have five spans with the class hiccup and name 'yup'.

```
$('span.hiccup').attr('name',function(i,v){return v + i;});
```

will give each span a name 'yup1' - 'yup5'.

Additionally, you have access to this inside the function, which refers to the element itself. Given this, you could probably do some really interesting stuff.

As always, jQuery has awesome documentation of all of this:
http://api.jquery.com/attr

Comment: @aepheus--What if your function returns a value for a completely new attribute? aka there is no previousValue

Answer (score 0):

There's a good example in jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), which I'll shorten here:

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div>Zero-th </div>
<div>First </div>
<div>Second </div>
```

If you then run this javascript it'll apply unique id's to each div:

```
$("div").attr("id", function (arr) {
  return "div-id" + arr;
});
```

The `$` function returns all of the div's so the `arr` argument allows you to specify the attribute value based on the index.

The function passed to attr also received a value specifying the old attribute value, but as this is javascript the function doesn't have to name that argument and it's still available in the `arguments`.